# How is '\x1A' special in Windows?

Tags: windows, fopen

Reading some references<sup>[1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen), [2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen)</sup>, I learned that the modifier `b` in the second argument in `fopen(3)` has no effect in POSIX systems, while it prevents special handling for `\n` and `\x1A` in Windows (See below).

I well know how `\n` (LF) is special in Windows as text files use CRLF for line break (i.e. `printf("\n")` actually prints `\r\n`), but how is `\x1A` (SUB) special?

```
fopen("D:\\foo.txt", "rb");
                       ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\x1A` is Ctrl+Z, which used to be used as the end-of-file marker in MS-DOS (maybe even as far back as CP/M).

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen) makes no mention of Ctrl+Z under the "b" mode (only under the "t" mode), so this could be cargo cult programming. I don't have a Windows box handy right now, so I can't easily check.

Comment: See [`_read`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/read), which states that "[i]f the file was opened in text mode, the read terminates when read encounters a CTRL+Z character, which is treated as an end-of-file indicator". Microsoft's CRT implements the high-level standard I/O API (e.g. `fread`) over a low-level POSIX layer (which is layered over the Windows API, e.g. `ReadFile`, which is layered over the NT API, e.g. `NtReadFile`). Some behaviors of standard I/O text mode are implemented at the POSIX low I/O level (e.g. via modes `_O_TEXT`, `_O_WTEXT`, etc).

Comment: Also, in case it's not obvious to the OP, 0x1A is decimal 26. ASCII control characters 1-26 are commonly mapped to Ctrl plus the corresponding letter in the English alphabet, in which "Z" is the 26th letter.